# Navigation items with custom views disappear in iOS 14

Tags: ios, storyboard, iboutlet, weak, ios14

Since updating my iPhone to iOS 14 beta 2 (and released 14.0) I have crashes due to `nil` implicitly-unwrapped (`!`) `weak` `@IBOutlets` and missing Storyboard-created left and right navigation items.

When running the app I can see the items appear and then quickly disappear.

I have tried removing `weak` to make the items strong with no luck.

Update:

It happens with all navigation items with custom views.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to add strong references to my button items containing custom views, and add them back on `viewDidAppear` (`viewWillAppear` doesn't seem to be enough).

Ugly, but works and urgently fixes the crashes. Also filed a bug report to Apple.